# jquery tablesorter with search option is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, tablesorter

I am trying to put a table sorter for my listing bootstrap table i am using jquery table sorter for making a search option.this search option is working in mozilla means(the inputbox for making search is displayed) but it's not showing in chrome browser. could you please help me to recover the browser compatibility issue.

I am attaching my output screenshot in chrome

[image]

And the same output in firefox is

[image]]

I am below attaching my code which I used.

```
$(function() {

    var $table = $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
        headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            1: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            2: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            3: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            5: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            6: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            7: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            8: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
            9: {
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            },
        },
        widgetOptions: {

            filter_external: '.search',
            filter_defaultFilter: {
                1: '~{query}'
            },
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            filter_placeholder: {
                search: 'Search...'
            },
            filter_saveFilters: true,
            filter_reset: '.reset'
        }
    });


    $('button[data-column]').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            totalColumns = $table[0].config.columns,
            col = $this.data('column'),
            filter = [];


        filter[col === 'all' ? totalColumns : col] = $this.text();
        $table.trigger('search', [filter]);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just invisible? Check the DOM to see whether it's there.

Comment: Looks more like 'webkit-appearance: none' to me, so a css issue and not a js problem.

Comment: actually the input box is there which am getting in chrome as                                                                       <input type="text" class="filter" data-col="4" style="">                                  but in firefox as                                                                                         <input class="filter" data-col="4" style="" type="text">

Comment: have you ever used the element inspector in google chrome ? this problem shoud be pretty easy to find...

Comment: Please share the HTML being used.